# Why my TryInvokeMember is not called?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamicobject

My DynamicObject implementation looks like this:

```
public class DynCallsite: DynamicObject
{
    public DynCallsite(ScriptPlayer player)
    {
        _player = player;
    }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        var ftt = new CallTranslator();

        var request = ftt.CreateXmlRequest(binder.Name, args);

        var callResult = _player.CallFunction(request);
        result = ftt.DeserializeXmlRequest(callResult);

        return true;            
    }

    private ScriptPlayer _player;
}
```

This is how I'm using the instance of this object:

```
class DynHost
{
    public DynHost()
    {
        _callSite = new DynCallsite(new ScriptPlayer());
    }    

    public dynamic Callsite
    {
        get { return _callsite; }   // A breakpoint put here will be hit
    }
}

// *snip*

var dh = new DynHost();
dh.Callsite.MyMethod("str1", 5, "str2");
```

It *used to* work :), I'm not sure what changed. The debugger is not breaking on the TryInvokeMember call and I'm getting a `RuntimeBinderException`. This class is defined in a different assembly than the running one (it is referenced the normal way, by adding references to the project from the same solution).

After performing a call on an instance, I'm getting the following stack trace:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.**SubmitError**(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Errors.CError
>   pError) + 0x23 bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.LangCompiler.**SubmitError**(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Errors.CParameterizedError
>   error) + 0x24 bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Errors.ErrorHandling.**ErrorTreeArgs**(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Errors.ErrorCode
>   id, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Errors.ErrArg[] prgarg) + 0x53
>   bytes 
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.MemberLookup.**ReportErrors**() +
>   0x6cd bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.**BindCall**(Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ICSharpInvokeOrInvokeMemberBinder
>   payload, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.EXPR callingObject,
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.ArgumentObject[]
>   arguments,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
>   dictionary) + 0x206 bytes 
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.**DispatchPayload**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   payload, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.ArgumentObject[]
>   arguments,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
>   dictionary) + 0xb1 bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.**BindCore**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   payload,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   parameters, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args, out
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject deferredBinding) + 0xbc bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.**Bind**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   payload,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   parameters, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args, out
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject deferredBinding) + 0x56 bytes
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.**Bind**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder
>   action, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder binder,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   args,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
>   arginfos, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject onBindingError) + 0x2ca
>   bytes 
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.**FallbackInvokeMember**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject
>   target, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args,
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion) + 0x77 bytes
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.MetaDynamic.BindInvokeMember.**AnonymousMethod__10**(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject
>   e) + 0x1b bytes
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicObject.MetaDynamic.**BindInvokeMember**(System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder
>   binder, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) + 0xb8 bytes 
>   System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder.Bind(System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject
>   target, System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject[] args) + 0x36 bytes 
>   System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(object[] args,
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection
>   parameters, System.Linq.Expressions.LabelTarget returnLabel) + 0xea
>   bytes 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.**BindCore**>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite>
>   site, object[] args) + 0x80 bytes 
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.**UpdateAndExecuteVoid3**(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite
>   site, object arg0, decimal arg1, double arg2) + 0x30e bytes
>   MyApp.DynCallsite.**MyMethod**(string str1, decimal number, string str2) Line 96 + 0x17d bytes    C#

It pretty much looks like as if I was using a DynamicObject instance instead of my specialized derived class. However, I confirmed that this is not the case, as I can inspect the callsite object in the debugger and it says DynCallsite. What could cause this?

Comment: You haven't shown how you're *using* the object. If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help.

Comment: to prevent `I'm not sure what changed` moments in the future, consider using a version control system such as [mercurial](http://hginit.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm on the good side now (happy git user for almost 2 years), but this is an old project where I wasn't :)

Comment: Hey I'm wondering if you should also override `TryGetMember` it returns true or false, telling the DLR weather the member exists in the instance.

Comment: I do have TryGetMember and TrySetMember implemented, but I think they are for property-type things (and they are implemented accordingly). As the script object will accept non-existing properties, they always return true (and get/set the dynamic properties on the player). And breakpoints in them are also not hit.

Comment: I think only option you have right now is to de-compile the compiler generated code and dive into it to understand what might be happening....your code looks OK to me and in fact I have been able to use your code in a stub and successfully run it...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you use dynamic directly it will work. The problem could be that you return it through property. This way works it in WPF databinding. If i give dynamic directly as DataContext, binding works. If I use property as you used I get bindig errors.